# Group by grepping for terms in a column with dplyr

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Symptom                                          number        

Abdominal pain\n Swallowing probs\n Back issues\n       22
Abdominal pain\n                                        12
Back issues \n Vomiting \n                                 14
Back issues\n                                            5
```

There is always a `\n` at the end of each symptom phrase. The symptom phrase itself can literally be anything so I don't want to search for these terms specifically, but rather any term before (or between) `\n`

I would like to average the `number` for each symptom so that I end up with:

```
Symptom                       Avg
Abdominal pain                 17
Swallowing probs               22
Back issues                    20.5
Vomiting                       14
```

I don't know how to group by the individual terms with dplyr. I have tried

```
SypmAvg<- df %>% group_by(grepl("(?\\n.*\\n)|($.*?\\n)",df$Symptom)%>% summarise(mean=mean(number)
```

but it just crashes my computer so I don't even get to see the error. Can anyone help? Is it just a regex issue or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "Symptom", "\\n", "long")[, .(Avg = mean(number)), .(Symptom)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that the Avg is just being done for the second half of the split. My numbers don't seem to add up

Comment: Aha. I think its because of the NA's. I guess I just have to put na.rm=T

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 = df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(new_col = strsplit(Symptom, "\n")) %>% unnest()

df1 %>% group_by(trimws(new_col)) %>% summarise( ans = mean(number))

# new_col   ans
# 1   Abdominal pain 17.00000
# 2      Back issues 13.66667
# 3 Swallowing probs 22.00000
# 4         Vomiting 14.00000
```

Comment: @SebastianZeki number didn't match for Back Issues... is yours correct?